# issue of undefined in typescript (intermediate value)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

[having this issue that crash my app right away, i don't know what is wrong with it?,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruBQC.png)

while i was doing useQuery nromally i didn't had that prob, but now i need the getServerSideProps as  i need to passs informations down 3 components .... and got this undefined. in jsx it will work, but typescript is not happ with it

```html
export default function Home({ data }):JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex flex-col  bg-gray-800 w-full items-center pb-10 ">
        <div className="flex flex-col max-w-screen-xl w-full ">
          <div className="flex flex-col text-white  w-full p-10 ">
            <div className="flex justify-between gap-10  ">
              <h1 className=" uppercase font-medium">
                <b>muhammad ali </b>
                vs
                <b> joe frazier</b>
              </h1>
              <p>New York, 1971 | 48:38</p>
            </div>
            <div className="w-full ">
              <HomeVideo />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const { loading, error, data } = await client.query({
    query: GET_ALL_VIDEOS,
  });
  return {
    props: {
      loading: loading,
      error: error || null,
      data: data,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: What is the return type of `client.query` if you ask typescript?

Comment: (method) ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>.query<any, OperationVariables>(options: QueryOptions<OperationVariables, any>): Promise<ApolloQueryResult<any>>  @aside

Comment: @aside this is the result while clicking on client.query 

(alias) const client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>
import client


(method) ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>.query<any, OperationVariables>(options: QueryOptions<OperationVariables, any>): Promise<ApolloQueryResult<any>>

Comment: Seems fine... Your issue is hard to pinpoint without access to the code at hand. If you could reproduce it in a codesandbox I could take a look.

Comment: hi @aside, i found the problem, my project got corrupted after a recovry point i had to do for another project.... so i just download again in another folder from my github and no problems with it, thanks a lot! now i have to fix other stuff before giving the test to my future employer :)

Comment: Glad you found a solution!